# Change which file vscode opens when using "go to definition"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm using Visual Studio Code to manage a C project that contains a number of libraries and fully-linked executables. When the executables need to depend on headers from a library, rather that point at the library's source files directly, they point at a build directory containing the headers. That is, for a source layout like:

- project/lib/src/lib.h
- project/exe/src/exe.c

Rather than the build for `project/exe` including `-I project/lib/src`, it does `-I project/lib/build`, which will have a copy of `lib.h` in it from the last time the library was built. This is done for miscellaneous reasons that don't matter here, and mostly works fine, except when I use vscode's "Go to Definition" feature (F12, Ctrl+Click, etc.).

Because vscode is using the compiler's include path to know where to find headers, if I go to the definition of anything in `lib.h`, vscode will open `project/lib/build/lib.h` instead of `project/lib/src/lib.h`. Is there a way, either built-in or via a plugin, to hook vscode's belief that it should open `project/lib/build/lib.h` and change it to `project/lib/src/lib.h`? I'm even willing to write a plugin, but I couldn't find a way to either modify the language server's result to change the path, or intercept vscode attempting to open a particular path and change it on-demand.

Comment: Try using `#include "absolute/path/to/your/intended/file" `